# Oracle Update Query From a C# interface

Tags: c#, oracle, sql-update

I'm having an issue with an update query in C#. It's odd to me that I'm having an issue with update, but select, delete, and insert work.

```
  public void updateTeacherInfo(string SSN, string Classroom, string salary, string tenured, string phone)
    {

        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("myconnectionstring;");

        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("Update Teachers Set classroom_number = :TRM, Salary = :TSALARY, Tenured = :TTENURE, Phone_numer = :TPHONE Where SSN = :TSSN", conn);
        OracleCommand commit = new OracleCommand("COMMIT", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":TSSN", SSN));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":TRM", Classroom));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":TSALARY", salary));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":TTENURE", tenured));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":TPHONE", phone));


       int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       int k = commit.ExecuteNonQuery();

       MessageBox.Show(i + " rows affected");
       MessageBox.Show(k + " rows affected");


        conn.Close();

    }
```

***Edit**** the rest of the method to clear things up, and also, it is not throwing any errors, but does not update the database.

Comment: What is setting the values of the parameters your are using?

Comment: Exactly how is it not working: error message? Nothing updated?

Comment: My C# interface, this is a method being called from form1, the variables are correct because I've previously had it giving me a message box listing all of the parameters.

Comment: Sorry, nothing is updated, but no error message what so ever.

Comment: A long shot: what is your SSN data type in C#, and what is its data type in Oracle? Also, does the SSN in question have a leading zero? I've had trouble in the past dealing with the C# type being numeric (`int`, `long`, etc.) and the Oracle type being string (`char`, `varchar2`, etc.), or the other way around, and the trouble seems to intensify when the SSN has a leading zero or two.

Comment: The data type in Oracle is number, this is actually coming in as a string. The reasoning for it is that's the way it had to be for the insert statement in another class.

Comment: You might want to bind parameters by name.

Answer (score 1):

Put the Parameters.Add in proper sequence. In your update query

```
"Update Teachers Set classroom_number = :TRM, Salary = :TSALARY, Tenured = :TTENURE, Phone_numer = :TPHONE Where SSN = :TSSN"
```

:TRM is occuring first and likewise. So keep the Parameters.Add also in same sequence. It will work. The sequence will be:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":TRM", Classroom));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":TSALARY", salary)); 
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":TTENURE", tenured));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":TPHONE", phone));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":TSSN", SSN));
```